# How to display server image in MVC razor where Image Url has path with IP address

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My imageUrl vairable contain something like this, `http://192.168.249.148/Photos/Teacher/30482/Subject/91/2017-11-30T17-14-53.5817073Z.png`

I have use following code to display the image in MVC razor view but it will not display in email body.

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.imageUrl)" alt="Image"/>
```

Is there any way to display image which has server path in MVC razor view?

Comment: Are you trying to send email with image in your mail body ?

Answer (score 0):

If `Model.imageUrl` has an **absolute url** (*which can be accessed via browser when you try that url*), you do not need to use the `Url.Content` method. Simply use the absolute url as the image src.

```
<img src="@Model.imageUrl" alt="Image"/>
```